# can I put an objective-C selector in a struct?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, selector

I was wanting to associate a set of rectangles with corresponding actions, so I tried to do

```
struct menuActions {
    CGRect rect;
    SEL action;
};

struct menuActions someMenuRects[] = {
    { { { 0, 0 }, {320, 60 } }, @selector(doSomething) },
    { { { 0, 60}, {320, 50 } }, @selector(doSomethingElse) },
};
```

but I get the error "initializer element is not constant".  Is there some reason that what I'm trying to do isn't allowed in general, or isn't allowed at global scope, or do I have some kind of minor punctuation mistake?

Comment: I don't know why `@selector` isn't constant, but if you can put the initialization into a function you wouldn't have to worry about that.

Comment: I didn't want to write code like someMenuRects[0].action = @doSomething, because then I might as well just do the same thing at runtime, i.e. if (CGRectContainsPoint(someMenuRects[0], pt)) { [self doSomething] }

Comment: A selector isn't constant because the value isn't really determined until very very early at runtime.  Thus, you can stick a string in there and do a lookup at runtime, if you want.

Comment: so for now I'm using a static table of (char *)s and just calling the selector via sel_registerName when it's chosen, since it's UI code and the extra call doesn't matter.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This answer is to why `"initializer element is not constant"`.

Given the following example:

```
SEL theSelector; // Global variable

void func(void) {
  theSelector = @selector(constantSelector:test:);
}
```

Compiles to something like this for the `i386` architecture:

```
  .objc_meth_var_names
L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_4:
  .ascii "constantSelector:test:\0"

  .objc_message_refs
  .align 2
L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5:
  .long   L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_4
```

This part defines two local (in terms of assembly code) 'variables' (actually labels), `L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_4` and `L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5`.  The text `.objc_meth_var_names` and `.objc_message_refs`, just before the 'variable' labels, tells the assembler which section of the object file to put "the stuff that follows".  The sections are meaningful to the linker.  `L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5` is initially set to the address of `L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_4`.

At execution load time, before the program begins executing, the linker does something approximately like this:

- Iterates over each entry in the `.objc_message_refs`
  section.
- Each entry is initially set to a pointer to a `0` terminated `C` string.
- In our example, the pointer is initially set to the
  address of `L_OBJC_METH_VAR_NAME_4`, which
  contains the `ASCII` `C` string 
  `"constantSelector:test:"`.
- It then performs 
  `sel_registerName("constantSelector:test:")`
  and stores the returned value at
  `L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5`.  The linker,
  which knows private implementation details,
  may not call `sel_registerName()` literally.

Essentially the linker performs this at load time for our example:

```
L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5 = sel_registerName("constantSelector:test:");
```

This is why the `"initializer element is not constant"`- the initializer element must be constant at compile time.  The value is not actually known until the program begins executing.  Even then, your `struct` declarations are stored in a different linker section, the `.data` section.  The linker only knows how to update `SEL` values in the `.objc_message_refs` section, and there is no way to 'copy' that run-time calculated `SEL` value from `.objc_message_refs` to some arbitrary location in `.data`.

The `C` source code...

```
theSelector = @selector(constantSelector:test:);
```

... becomes:

```
  movl    L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5, %edx // The SEL value the linker placed there.
  movl    L_theSelector$non_lazy_ptr, %eax   // The address of theSelector.
  movl    %edx, (%eax)                       // theSelector = L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5;
```

Since the linker does all its work before the program is executing, `L_OBJC_SELECTOR_REFERENCES_5` contains the exact same value you would get if you were to call `sel_registerName("constantSelector:test:")`:

```
theSelector = sel_registerName("constantSelector:test:");
```

The difference is this is a function call, and the function needs to do the actual work of finding the selector if its already been registered, or go through the process of allocating a new `SEL` value to register the selector.  This is considerably slower that just loading a constant value.  Though this is 'slower', it does allow you to pass an arbitrary `C` string.  This can be useful if:

- The selector is not known at compile time.
- The selector is not known until just before `sel_registerName()` is called.
- You need to vary the selector dynamically at run time.

All selectors need to pass through `sel_registerName()`, which registers each `SEL` exactly once.  This has the advantage of having exactly one value, everywhere, for any given selector.  Though an implementation private detail, `SEL` is "usually" just a `char *` pointer to a copy of the selectors `C` string text.

Now you know.  And knowing is half the battle!

Comment: thanks for the details.  I was assuming that the sel_registerName happened at compile/link time, rather than at load time, for a constant selector...  so I guess sel_registerName is really only "slower" if you call it >1 time...

Comment: Wow... didn't understand the half, but sounds like you know what you talking about ) +1

Comment: _“the function needs to do the actual work of finding the selector if its already been registered”_: exactly. E.G. If an app source file used `@selector(constantSelector:test:)`, a dynamic lib (framework) also used that selector, and if some dynamic runtime code did a `sel_registerName("constantSelector:test:")`, Objective-C assures those all return the same `SEL` (AKA `struct objc_selector *`) pointer at runtime. This feature makes selectors effectively interned strings in order to make selector equality-comparisons (and thus, lookups) really fast— a pointer comparison is all that's needed..

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
struct menuActions {
   CGRect rect;
   const char *action;
};

struct menuActions someMenuRects[] = {
   { { { 0, 0 }, {320, 60 } }, "doSomething" },
   { { { 0, 60}, {320, 50 } }, "doSomethingElse" },
};
```

At runtime, register the selectors:

```
int numberOfActions = 2;
for (int i=0; i < numberOfActions; i++)
   NSLog (@"%s", sel_registerName(someMenuRects[i].action));
```

Output:

```
[Session started at 2009-09-11 16:16:12 -0700.]
2009-09-11 16:16:14.527 TestApp[12800:207] @selector(doSomething)
2009-09-11 16:16:14.531 TestApp[12800:207] @selector(doSomethingElse)
```

More about `sel_registerName()` at the [Objective-C 2.0 Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-BCIGFJBB).

Comment: yes, I was aware of sel_registerName, but again in principle it seems wrong to do this step at runtime when it's really determined at compile-time.  perhaps the answer to my question is really just "no, you can't", and I should ask another question like "what's the best way to build a function dispatch table in Objective-C"...

Comment: I didn't mean to assume ignorance on your part. It's an interesting question, but I don't know the right answer.

Comment: sorry if I sounded offended--I'm plenty ignorant on this platform!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're reinventing NSCell here.  If you want to implement a menu, why not use existing UI classes?